# Running files in Linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

On a Mac one can run any downloaded executable in the terminal using just the executable name. On Linux, such as Ubuntu, by default one will have to specify the directory to run in.

Mac example: sbt

Linux example: ./sbt

What do I need to set in Linux so that I don't need the ./ in front of the executable?

Comment: Add `.` to your $PATH env var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
PATH=$PATH:.
```

or in bash:

```
PATH+=:.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an alias in your .bashrc file if it is an often used file. Or just add the directory in which your files is located to your $PATH var.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your script in /usr/local/bin